# Understanding Linear Independed

Tags: linear-algebra

{$e^{x}$,$e^{2x}$} viewed as a subset of $\mathbb{R} ^{\mathbb{R} }$ is linear independed.

Proof. Suppose $a_{1}e^{x}+a_{2}e^{2x}=0$ and $a_{1},a_{2}\neq 0$.

for $x=0 \rightarrow a_{1}+a_{2}=0$

for $x=1 \rightarrow a_{1}+ea_{2}=0$

These equations yield $a_{1}=ea_{2}$ and this, in turn, yields $1=e$ as $a_{2}\neq 0$. Contradiction.

My question is that why contradiction? It can not be contradiction since either $a_{1}$  or $a_{2}$  were not equal to zero.

Comment: I don't really get what you're saying. Do you disagree that $1=e$ is a contradiction? If you don't, then do you disagree that the equations yield $1=e$?

Answer (score 1):

It is because the first equation gives $a_2 = -a_1$ and the second gives $ea_2 = -a_1$, so we have $a_2 = ea_2$. Since we assume $a_2 \neq 0$, we can cancel it on both sides to get $1 = e$. It would have to be $a_2$ = 0 to avoid this problem. But this contradicts our assumption that $a_2 \neq 0$, right in the beggining. Ok?

Comment: Ah! Yes, of course! Thanks.